# Postgres Regular Expression Positive Lookbehind with Repetition

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Working for the first time with Postgres flavor regular expressions and stumped on it's behavior here.

```
Input: 'xxxaaabc'

Expected: 'xxxaaazzzbc'
```

Logic: Match M a's, capture group, and add 'zzz' directly after the sequence

Attempts:

```
select regexp_replace('aaabc','(?!\Sa+)','zzz','i')

Result: zzzxxxaaabc

select regexp_replace('aaabc','(?!\Sa+)','zzz','i')

Result: xxxazzzaabc

select select regexp_replace('xxxaaabc','(?!=a+)','zzz','i')

Result: zzzxxxaaabc
```

This one seems to get pretty close regexp_replace('aaabc','(?!\Sa+)','zzz','i'), but the repetition of a's isn't working.

Comment: I think you want `select regexp_replace('xxxaaabc','(a+)','\1zzz','i') AS Result;` ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ev-QSRY_))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the `(?!\Sa+)` pattern matches an empty location that is not immediately followed with a single non-whitespace char and then one or more `a` chars.

The `(?!=a+)` pattern matches a location in a string, that is not immediately followed with `=` and then one or more `a`s.

You can capture one or more `a`s and then use a backreference to the match and then just append the `zzz`:

```sql
select regexp_replace('xxxaaabc','(a+)','\1zzz','i') AS Result;
```

See the [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ev-QSRY_).